# Android Listview/ListFragment inside ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I am new to android so please explain me in detail.

I have a class which extend ListFragment

```
public class ProfileFragment extends ListFragment{  

    /** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
    String profile_list[] = new String[]{
            "Personal Info",
            "Account Info"

    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, profile_list);

        /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    }    

    @Override
    public void onStart() {     
        super.onStart();

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item " + pos + " was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I want to add child list with some arrow indication (have child or not). I can not upload the image otherwise it will explain more clearly.

If I click on (Account Info) item two more rows come below the (Account Info) and disappear when click again on Account Info.

Please asnwer me in steps with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for in particular, `ExpandableListView`, to explain in brief, it helps to display views group wise, like in your case as you said, when you click a particular item it should expand and display further items beneath that view, this functionality is supported by `ExpandableListView` by default, all you need to do is divide your data in groups, and plug them into adapter linking it to expandable listview and wollah you're done, check below link for more detail.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: I am using ListFragment can you please tell me ExpandableListFragment instead of ExpandableListView. I do not want to change my code. I have 3 tab in it each tab have a ListFragment.

Comment: There is no such fragment, instead you create a Tabbed activity and implement rest if UI logic using expandable list view, Like have one container for fragment, then create three fragments(not list fragment), implement there ui using expandable list view, and upon pressing of tabs, just make the proper fragment transactions.